# Highlight "Show all" item in wp_list_categories

Tags: theme-development, filters, hooks, categories

I use `wp_list_categories` to display category filters on post archives.

I can use `current_category` param to set current category - and such item will get addition class `current-cat`. I can even omit this param - in such case the current category will come from `get_queried_object()`.

But... I want to show "Show all" link in that navigation. All i have to do is to use `show_option_all` param.

And here's my problem. How can I highlight this option, when no category is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no filter allowing to modify the "Show all" link directly or to add any class to this item:

```
$output .= "<li class='cat-item-all'><a href='$posts_page'>$show_option_all</a></li>";
```

But there is a `wp_list_categories` at the end of function that allows you to modify all the output. Here's a filter that will highlight "Show all" option if no `current_category` is set and we're not visiting any term from given taxonomy.

```
function wp_list_categories_highlight_all( $output, $args ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'show_option_all', $args ) && $args['show_option_all'] ) {
        if ( ! array_key_exists( 'current_category', $args ) || $args['current_category'] ) {
            if ( is_category() || is_tax() || is_tag() ) {
                if ( ! array_key_exists( 'taxonomy', $args ) ) {
                    $args['taxonomy'] = 'category';
                }
                $current_term_object = get_queried_object();
                if ( $args['taxonomy'] !== $current_term_object->taxonomy ) {
                    $output = str_replace( "class='cat-item-all'", "class='cat-item-all current-cat'", $output );
                }
            } else {
                $output = str_replace( "class='cat-item-all'", "class='cat-item-all current-cat'", $output );
            }
        }
    }

    return $output;
}
add_filter( 'wp_list_categories', 'wp_list_categories_highlight_all', 10, 2 );
```